# Assign background colour to cell if value differs from value in previous row

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel Table:**

```
     |      A       
-----|------------------------------
1    |  Product_A
2    |  Product_A
3    |  Product_A
4    |  Product_B
5    |  Product_C
6    |  Product_C
7    |  Product_D
8    |  Product_D
9    |  Product_E
10   |  Product_E
11   |  Product_E
12   |  Product_F 
13   |
```

---

In `Column A` I want to achive that the **same products** get the **same** `background colour`.

The `background colour` should swtich between `yellow RGB(255,255,0)` and `gray RGB (217,217,217)` so in the end `Column A` looks like this:

[image]

---

I have no clue what kind of `VBA` I need to achieve this. 
I guess it is something like this:

```
Sub Background_colour()

If product_from_previous_row <> product_from_current_row AND Sheet1.Range("A:A").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 
THEN Sheet1.Range("A:A").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 0)
Else

  If product_from_previous_row <> product_from_current_row AND Sheet1.Range("A:A").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
  THEN Sheet1.Range("A:A").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
  End If

End If
Do Until Sheet1.Range("A:A").Value = ""
Loop

End Sub
```

Do you have any idea what `VBA` I need to get the switching `colour background` as in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for.

Change the sheetname to whatever your actual sheet is called. And if you want to use this in multiple workbooks then change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`

```
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim grey As Long
        Dim yellow As Long
        Dim colortouse As Long
        grey = RGB(217, 217, 217) 
        yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        For i = 1 To lr
            If i = 1 Then
                colortouse = grey
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).Value <> .Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
                If colortouse = grey Then
                    colortouse = yellow
                Else
                    colortouse = grey
                End If
            End If
            .Cells(i, 1).Interior.color = colortouse
        Next i
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative: you can achieve this via a hidden helper column then use conditional formatting to band the data.

For example:

> With data to be banded in column B and a hidden helper column in column A

```
i)   Assign A2: FALSE

ii)  Assign A3: =IF(B3<>"",IF(B3<>B2,NOT(A2),A2),FALSE)

iii) Assign CF (formula based): =IF($A3=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
     Assign fill colour and extend row range for CF if wanted

iV)  Autofill downwards
```